# ElasticSearch - Complicated Order on 2 fields?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this sample data

```
Name: A
Price: 200
PromotionPrice: 100
PromotionStart: 2020/01/01
PromotionEnd:   2020/01/15
```

`PromotionPrice` would be 0 if there is no promotion on them

I would like to sort those have `PromotionPrice` comming first (`asc` or `desc`) and those dont have `PromotionPrice` coming later. (filter out those have `PromotionPrice` but out of promotion time range)

I tried working on `_script` but it's too complicated for me.

### Currently working on version 7.

My mapping:

```
"Price" : {"type": "long"}
"PromotionPrice": {"type": "long"},
"PromotionStart": {"type": "date"},  
"PromotionEnd": {"type": "date"},
```

---

My code:
Sort by `Price` or `PromotionPrice` but did not prioritize those items with promotion first.

```
"sort": [
            {
                "_script": {
                    "type": "number",
                    "script": {
                        "lang": "painless",
                        "params": {
                            "now": "120000000"
                        },
                        "source": "if (doc['PromotionPrice'].value != 0 && params.now <= doc['PromotionEnd'].value.getMillis() && params.now >= doc['PromotionStart'].value.getMillis()) {doc['selling_price'].value} else {doc['normal_price'].value}"
                    },
                    "order": "asc"
                }
            }
        ]
```

---

Expected Result:

```
Name: A
Price: 200
PromotionPrice: 100
PromotionStart: 2020/11/01
PromotionEnd:   2020/12/01

Name: B
Price: 500
PromotionPrice: 200
PromotionStart: 2020/11/01
PromotionEnd:   2020/12/01


Name: C
Price: 500
PromotionPrice: 300
PromotionStart: 2020/11/01
PromotionEnd:   2020/12/01


Name: E
Price: 100
PromotionPrice: 0
PromotionStart: 2020/11/01
PromotionEnd:   2020/12/01


Name: D                              
Price: 500               #have PromotionPrice but treated as not having 
PromotionPrice: 300      #cuz out of promotion time range
PromotionStart: 2020/11/01
PromotionEnd:   2020/11/05
```

---

Further topic:

Based on the logic of @Val:

If I would like to sort `asc` or `desc` those with promotion above:

with `now` and `type` would be included in `params`

```
def isPromo = (doc.new_price.value > 0 && doc.start_date.value.getMillis() <  Long.parseLong(params.now) && doc.end_date.value.getMillis() >  Long.parseLong(params.now)); 
if (isPromo? && if (params.type == 'asc') {return true;} return false;) 
(return doc.new_price.value: (doc.price.value+100000000) return doc.new_price.value: (doc.price.value-100000000
```

Sad that this one not working

Comment: Would be easy for us to provide working example, if you can share you mapping, sample data and expected output

Comment: @ElasticsearchNinja , sorry for providing a question with lack of information, please check it again as I updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great start, your script almost contains the right logic, you just need to add a constant to the regular price as you'll see in my response below.

The following script can help you sort your results the way you expect. The way it works is inlined in comments into the script:

```
POST promotions/_search
{
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "type": "number",
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": """
        // current time
        def now = new Date().getTime();

        // check if the current product satisfies to the promotion constraints
        def isPromo = (doc.PromotionPrice.value > 0 && doc.PromotionStart.value.getMillis() < now && doc.PromotionEnd.value.getMillis() > now);

        // if the product qualifies for promotion return its promotion price, otherwise return its normal price + a constant
        return isPromo ? doc.PromotionPrice.value : (doc.Price.value + 100000000);
        """
      },
      "order": "asc"
    }
  }
}
```

Results:

```
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "promotions",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "ilucrHUB7CBHpnCGfnBn",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "Name" : "A",
          "Price" : 200,
          "PromotionPrice" : 100,
          "PromotionStart" : "2020-11-01",
          "PromotionEnd" : "2020-12-01"
        },
        "sort" : [
          100.0
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "promotions",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "i1ucrHUB7CBHpnCGfnBn",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "Name" : "B",
          "Price" : 500,
          "PromotionPrice" : 200,
          "PromotionStart" : "2020-11-01",
          "PromotionEnd" : "2020-12-01"
        },
        "sort" : [
          200.0
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "promotions",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "jFucrHUB7CBHpnCGfnBn",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "Name" : "C",
          "Price" : 500,
          "PromotionPrice" : 300,
          "PromotionStart" : "2020-11-01",
          "PromotionEnd" : "2020-12-01"
        },
        "sort" : [
          300.0
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "promotions",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "jVucrHUB7CBHpnCGfnBn",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "Name" : "E",
          "Price" : 100,
          "PromotionPrice" : 0,
          "PromotionStart" : "2020-11-01",
          "PromotionEnd" : "2020-12-01"
        },
        "sort" : [
          1.000001E8
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "promotions",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "jlucrHUB7CBHpnCGfnBn",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "Name" : "D",
          "Price" : 500,
          "PromotionPrice" : 300,
          "PromotionStart" : "2020-11-01",
          "PromotionEnd" : "2020-11-05"
        },
        "sort" : [
          1.000005E8
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Comment: It works but I just cant make it sorts `asc`or `desc`for products with promotion above, mind you having a look on my latest JSON above, thanks

Comment: I don't understand what your code is doing... You cannot return a boolean AND a value at the same time.